# How can I prompt user to make a Facebook post without using Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to have the user press a button in my app and it would take them to Facebook with the message already typed out. Below is what I do for Twitter. Is there something similar I can do for Facebook without having to integrate the Facebook SDK?

```
public void twitterTweetButtonPressed(View view)
    {
        String tweetUrl = String.format("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%s&url=%s", urlEncode("My tweet goes here"), urlEncode(""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tweetUrl));

        List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo info : matches)
        {
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.twitter")) {
                intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            }
        }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Prefilling the message is not possible and against Facebook Platform Policy. I suggest that your read https://developers.facebook.com/policy and specifically 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code opens the official Facebook app directly if it's installed, and otherwise falls back to opening sharer.php in a browser.

```
String urlToShare = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534813";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB: has no effect!
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

// See if official Facebook app is found
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) {
    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
        intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
        facebookAppFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

// As fallback, launch sharer.php in a browser
if (!facebookAppFound) {
    String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Hope my above code will help you.

Let me know if you need more help from my side.

Comment: Thanks. What if I don't want to share a url though? Would if I just want to post text? Like a status message.

Comment: No its not possible. If you want to share then you can share via URL without facebook SDK

Comment: Oh ok. Is it possible to put a title for the link? I tried uncommenting the line (intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Foo bar"); // NB: has no effect!) but that did not work.

Comment: EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_BODY will not work in facebook application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can basically do the same thing using package name **com.facebook.katana** with the same action (`ACTION_VIEW`) and using extra Intent.EXTRA_TEXT to set the text.